# Polygon edges on the smooth object

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a problem rendering a label.
I shaded planes smooth, but somehow in render I see the edges. What's the possible solution to the problem?

[image]

Comment: Edges are definitely there but they do seem kind of softened.  Have you left a bevel modifier on?

Comment: No. there is no bevel modifier or any other modifier. I think, it's the denoiser.
It was a cylinder, that a cut a made a label out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the subdivision surface modifier. I don’t know if shade smooth works in render. Or just in the viewport.

Comment: Subdivision surface modifier didn't work out, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Could you post the .blend file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W-gy4t5j1CYeYb3BY5_-u182jqio_kdh?usp=sharing

Here's the blend file. Couldn't figure out how to attach them here, sorry.

Comment: I just added a bit of thickness (0.001) and the sub surface modifier worked.

Comment: Thanks!
You applied thickness with solidify modifier, right?
Which are the parametrs for sub surface modifier that you used?